# Web browser is not showing anything

Tags: android

Anyone can take a look at my code and let me know what I am missing?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mWebView.loadUrl("https://yahoo.com");
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    mWebView.loadUrl("https://apple.com");
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkit);
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml (layout file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webkit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My code is at: https://github.com/tlkahn/neonx

If you think this is too vague or off-topic, please comment and I will close it.

Comment: Please try doing `mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com")` outside `mWebView.setWebViewClient()`. If this works it means at you must manually load the mWebView.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so fast! I tried and it sees not working. I have pushed the change to github.

Comment: Please check your network status which may affect, (may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4239019/10941112 for connectivity code). Also I am working on your the code from git.

Comment: I just did and traced the program. It seems network is fine: https://github.com/tlkahn/neonx/commit/c52195102ea9044136b0fcbf918c8c3b6e28fa99

Comment: Answer given by Bek. Also you have another major issue at possibly `com.neonxorg.neonx.MyView`

Comment: Thanks! I just accepted it. Can I know more about the issue please? Also if you want to log an issue, please kindly.

Comment: The error has been reported to your Github repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
            return true;
        }
    });
```

With

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

            return false;
        }
    });
```

> Give the host application a chance to take control when a URL is about
>   to be loaded in the current WebView. If a WebViewClient is not
>   provided, by default WebView will ask Activity Manager to choose the
>   proper handler for the URL. If a WebViewClient is provided, **returning
>   true causes the current WebView to abort loading the URL**, while
>   returning false causes the WebView to continue loading the URL as
>   usual.

Comment: A textbook showcase that I should always check counsel the official doc in the first place when I ran into issues.

Comment: Yes, in most cases official doc is enough.

Answer (score 1):

So far from what I can tell you are supposed to extend the WebViewClient class with a separate class:

```
   private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url);
         return true;
      }
   }
```

and then set it to the WebViewClient:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
```

Also try adding settings for loading images automatically, enabling javascript and setting scrollbar:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        case R.id.navigation_home:
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://yahoo.com");
            return true;
        case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
            return true;
        case R.id.navigation_notifications:
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://apple.com");
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android 8+ then you must have to do 2 things.

1. Add this `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` attribute in manifest application tag. AndroidManifest.xml
2. you should override this method.

   ```
       mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
       @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

          view.load(request.getUrl().toString()) 

           return true;
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did already have the line: https://github.com/tlkahn/neonx/blob/b1d61245e875ecabf568831eea5d99dcef394fc3/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L14

Comment: keep both  shouldOverrideUrlLoading() or add targeted api lolipop to this method. just for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://facebook.com");
            return true;
        }
    });
```